# Flutter - how do I send/receive data between different class?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to get a current user location to update nearby stores based on latitude/longitude inside the url.

but I can't figure out how to interact data between two different class.
I want to make it work something like 'AppConfig.latitude = _position.latitude;'. I tried with several methods including inherited widget that I found on stackoverflow and youtube, but still don't work. It's definitely that I'm missing something.

when I use a bloc, I have no clue how to update data inside 'class AppConfig' with bloc. Can it be done simply using SetState? I spent the whole day yesterday Googling for this problem. please guide me to right approach

```
class _CurrentLocationState extends State<CurrentLocation> {
  Position _position;

Future<void> _initPlatformState() async {
    Position position;
    try {
      final Geolocator geolocator = Geolocator()
    ...

    setState(() {
      _position = position;

      // print(${_position.latitude})
      // 35.9341...
      // print(${_position.longitude})
      // -117.0912...

      <*I want to make it work something like this*>
      AppConfig.latitude = _position.latitude;
      AppConfig.longitude = _position.longitude;

      <*this is how I tried with bloc*>
      latLongBloc.getUserLocation(LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude));

    });
```

```
<* latitude/longitude need to be updated with a current user location *>
abstract class AppConfig {
  static const double latitude = 0;
  static const double longitude = 0;
  static const List<String> storeName = ['starbucks'];
}

<* I need to use AppConfig.latitude for url in Repository class*>
class Repository {
  ...
  Future<List<Business>> getBusinesses() async {

    String webAddress =
      "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?latitude=${AppConfig.latitude}&longitude=${AppConfig.longitude}&term=${AppConfig.storeName}";

  ...
}
```

this is my bloc.dart file

```
class LatLongBloc {

  StreamController _getUserLocationStreamController = StreamController<LatLng>();

  Stream get getUserLocationStream => _getUserLocationStreamController.stream;


  dispose(){
    _getUserLocationStreamController.close();
  }

  getUserLocation(LatLng userLatLong) {
    _getUserLocationStreamController.sink.add(userLatLong);
  }
}

final latLongBloc = LatLongBloc();
```

Comment: use getter and setter.

Comment: Is your _CurrentLocationState a stateful class?

Comment: @R.Duggan yes I'm still googling stackoverflow about getter/setter, and struggle using them with stateful widget.

Answer (score 0):

You want to share state between classes/widgets, right? There are also other state management patterns like `ScopedModel` or `Redux`. Each pattern has its pros and cons, but you don't have to use BLoC if you don't understand it.

I would recommend to use `ScopedModel` because it's quite easy to understand in my opinion. Your data/state is in a central place and can be accessed by using `ScopedModel`. If you don't like to use this approach then try `Redux` or other patterns :)

Hope it helped you :D

Yours Glup3